# anaconda install, torch-activate: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, anaconda

I'm trying to install anaconda on a remote server. I've allowed it to add something to `~/.bashrc` but now instead of starting up with the VM, it just gives me this:

```
xex2@graphite:~/anaconda3/bin$ source ~/.bashrc
-bash: /usr/local/torch/install/bin/torch-activate: No such file or directory
```

I assume this has something to do with the fact that there are multiple users on my server, but Anaconda is trying to install for all users, hence the `/usr/...` (can someone confirm?).

I'm trying to debug it by reading through what's going on in `~/.bashrc`, and maybe find the place where I need to fix the path. Sadly, I don't understand what's going on at all:

```
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/xex2/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/xex2/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/xex2/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/home/xex2/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

Has anyone dealt with this before and know how to solve it? Or can someone decode what's going on in this snippet of `~/.bashrc` so I know which file to look in next?

Comment: There is nothing in there about `torch`. The torch must be from something else, Anaconda will not change that. Also, as written in your script fragment, Anaconda is definitely not installing for all users in `/usr/` Do you want it to? What command are you using to install Anaconda?

Comment: My guess is that this has nothing to do with conda. Your server has a faulty torch, or some code that interacts with torch.

Comment: I do not want it to install for all users. I used `conda install pytorch torchvision cuda92 -c pytorch`.